¿Por que tengo este error: Cannot invoke "javax.persistence.EntityManager.createQuery(String, java.lang.Class)" because "this.entityManager" is null?
Estoy trabajando con Spring Boot y hibernate de java, pero, no he logrado salir del error mencionado en el titulo, de echo la aplicacion compila bien y se ejecuta, pero cuando trato de consultar algún controlador el cual realice una consulta a base de datos, no funciona bien.
Esta es la Clase Repository que estoy usando:
@Repository
public abstract class BaseRepository<T extends BaseEntity, ID extends Serializable> implements IBaseRepository<T, ID> {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private final Class<T> entityClass;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public BaseRepository() {
        this.entityClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public T save(T entity) {
        if (entity.getId() == null) {
            entityManager.persist(entity);
        } else {
            entityManager.merge(entity);
        }
        return entity;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<T> findById(ID id) {
        T entity = entityManager.find(entityClass, id);
        return Optional.ofNullable(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> findAll() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("from " + entityClass.getName(), entityClass).getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void delete(T entity) {
        if (entityManager.contains(entity)) {
            entityManager.remove(entity);
        } else {
            T managedEntity = entityManager.find(entityClass, entity.getId());
            if (managedEntity != null) {
                entityManager.remove(managedEntity);
            }
        }
    }
}

Aquí la clase que inicia la Aplicación:
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "actividad3.desechosfabrica.models.repositories")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "actividad3.desechosfabrica.models.entities")
public class DesechosfabricaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DesechosfabricaApplication.class, args);
    }

}


¿Tienes configurada una conexión a tu base de datos en el fichero .properties o .yml?

Bueno, no manejo la conexión por un archivo .yml , si no mas bien a través de un archivo application.properties.

BaseRepository es una clase abstracta. La propiedad @PersistenceContext private EntityManager entityManager; debería estar en las clases hijas o no será correctamente inyectada.
Mi consejo es que uses directamente interfaces que extiendan JpaRepository, te permitirá olvidarte completamente de la implementación.

Mi consejo es el mismo que Pablo Lozano, utiliza una interface que herede de JpaRepository indica la clase y el tipo de dato del ID (JpaRepository<Clase, Tipo_dato_id> y de ahí inyectas dependencias en el servicio y el controlador.
